# cudaErrorInvalidValue (0n11)

Tags: cuda, nvidia

I have a GTX 970 with CUDA 7.5, and compiling with compute capability of 5.2. When I run this kernel with the following dimensions I get cudaErrorInvalidValue. Are these dimensions valid for this kernel or am I missing something else?

```
dim3 blockDim(4, 4, 4);
dim3 gridDim((width + blockDim.z - 1)/ blockDim.z,
                 (height + blockDim.y - 1) / blockDim.y,
                 (depth + blockDim.z - 1) / blockDim.z);
icabsm_kernel<<<gridDim, blockDim>>>(threeDim,
                                           b_count,
                                           width,
                                           height,
                                           depth,
                                           dev_md,
                                           dev_d0,
                                           dev_d1,
                                           dev_num_fibers,
                                           dev_fr,
                                           dev_fib_fa,
                                           dev_fib_dir,
                                           dev_g_dg,
                                           dev_invg_dg,
                                           dev_signalData);
cudaError_t err = cudaGetLastError();
if(err != cudaSuccess)
    printf("Error: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
cudaDeviceSynchronize();
```

width = 96, height = 96, and depth = 72, 
which I get:

```
blockDim = {4, 4, 4}
gridDim = {24, 24, 18}
```

PS. I have looked at all other solutions and neither made sense in my case.
Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**: In my last cudaMalloc, I have forgotten to multiply the size by sizeof(float) and cudaMemcpy was saying the sizes don't match!! stupid me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Are these dimensions valid for this kernel or am I missing something else?

Those dimensions by themselves should not produce any error on kernel launch.

Here is a fully worked example:

```
$ cat t19.cu
#include <stdio.h>

__global__ void tkernel(){

  if ((!threadIdx.x) && (!threadIdx.y) && (!threadIdx.z) && (!blockIdx.x) && (!blockIdx.y) && (!blockIdx.z)) 
    printf("hello from kernel\n");
}

int main(){

  int width = 96;
  int height = 96;
  int depth = 72;
  dim3 blockDim(4, 4, 4);
  dim3 gridDim((width + blockDim.z - 1)/ blockDim.z,
                 (height + blockDim.y - 1) / blockDim.y,
                 (depth + blockDim.z - 1) / blockDim.z);

  tkernel<<<gridDim, blockDim>>>();
  cudaError_t err = cudaGetLastError();
  if(err != cudaSuccess)
    printf("Error1: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  err = cudaGetLastError();
  if(err != cudaSuccess)
    printf("Error2: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
}
$ nvcc -o t19 t19.cu -arch=sm_52
$ cuda-memcheck ./t19
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
hello from kernel
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

Your problem lies in something you haven't shown.

Comment: After I looked at your code, I decided to put error check before kernel launch, and indeed the error was for previous cuda call. Thanks for your response. Lesson learned !!!!!